# MySql - Insert more values in one field

Tags: mysql, node.js

I want to insert in a MYSQL field more than one value (more categories), to filter them afterwards.

```
router.get("/createtable", (req, res) => {
  let sql =
    "CREATE TABLE entries(id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,categories VARCHAR(255), title VARCHAR(255), kindof VARCHAR(255), image01 VARCHAR(255), image02 VARCHAR(255), image03 VARCHAR(255), website VARCHAR(255))";
  let query = connection.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send("Table created");
  });
});
```

the creation works perfectly.

```
router.post("/addentry", (req, res) => {

// I give to mysql this object:
  let entry = {
    categories: [req.body.categories], // I tried to give it as an array 
    title: req.body.title,
    kindof: req.body.kindof,
    image01: req.body.image01,
    image02: req.body.image02,
    image03: req.body.image03,
    website: req.body.website,
  };


  let sql = "INSERT INTO entries SET ?";
  let query = connection.query(sql, entry, (err, results) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(results);
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send("Entry added to MauerApp DB");
  });
});
```

Works perfectly with one value: `'category1'` . But when I try to insert more `('category1,category2')` it gives me back:

```
code: 'ER_OPERAND_COLUMNS',
[0]   errno: 1241,
[0]   sqlMessage: 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)',
[0]   sqlState: '21000',
[0]   index: 0,
[0]   sql: "INSERT INTO entries SET `categories` = ('clothing', 'jewerly'), `title` = '1', `kindof` = 'design', `image01` = '3', `image02` = '4', `image03` = '5', `website` = '2'"
[0] }
```

any idea? thanks!

Comment: You have M:N relation which needs in two entiny tables (items and categories) and junction table (items_to_categories). If an item has 2 category values then there is 2 rows in jinction table for this item.

Comment: sounds good but can you explain it a bit better? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is not a good design to have multiple values in single column. 
Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form. 
You should split it into two tables: entries and categories, and add foreign key 'id' in categories table to link it to entries; so you can have multiple categories for same entry.

If you must do it in same column (not recommended highly), you need to concatenate all the values in req.body.categories

Comment: Clear thanks for the hint. I have found a few intresting tutorial and I'm gonna try it

Comment: Alright. I suggest reading more about database normalization. Good luck!

Comment: based on what you told me (and I read) I prepared a second table(categories) with id, title, and category to link to the "main" table (entries). Now my query inserts in two table correctly and on the second table I get:   `{ "id": 21,"category": " clothing,illustration","title": "1"}` , as you can see the looks like the values are in the same field. is it correct?

Comment: So you need table no.1 : Entries with fields id, title, image... etc. etc.
Table no. 2 : Categories with fields id, category. Here id is a foreign key to Entries.id.
So when you are inserting data, you need to make 2 queries, one to insert into the Entries table, and other to insert into categories. When you insert into Entries, get the id returned by connection.query. Use this id, and your categories (res.body.categories) and make another query to insert to categories table.

Comment: Is what I did but I would like to know how to get more fields with the same ID. I opened a thread. thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Either you:

- convert your array categories into a string.

It can be a json, array serialised (don't recommend) or a string divided by an aggregator (for example a comma).

- Create a table to work as pivot between entries and categories.